# HTML image display

Tags: html, jtemplate

I have an html file where i am loading images from an xml file in to it. i am using jtemplate for that. I am getting the images properly.but i want to display them horizontaly those are coming as vertical. Please help me to do that,This is the sample.

Comment: can you post some ouput markup?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img …><img …><img …>
```

By default, images are inline. They will appear in a horizontal row (subject to word wrapping) unless you add additional markup or styling to make it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rotate images in HTML or with javascript. You need to use some serverside programming language as PHP to crop or rotate image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the sum of widths of your images is less than the width of the container.